# MessageDlg with Custom button text

Tags: delphi

According to the Parameter hints in Delphi 11.1 the MessageDlg should support custom button names defined in an array of strings in the last parameter.
e.g.[image]

I cannot get this to work.  I declared a constant 3 element array of string but the compiler claims there is no overloaded version of MessageDlg with this format.

Can anyone show me how this should work or is it an error in the parameter help.

Comment: Please show your actual code.

Comment: I might be biased, but personally I prefer Andreas Rejbrand's fluent task dialog interface: https://specials.rejbrand.se/dev/classes/TDMessageBox/TDMessageBox.html

Comment: But `MessageDlg` also works: `MessageDlg('Where do you want to go today?', TMsgDlgType.mtCustom, mbOKCancel, 0, TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK, ['Redmond', 'New York'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no problem it works fine

```
var
CustomButtonCaptions: array of string;
begin
 SetLength(CustomButtonCaptions , 5 );
 CustomButtonCaptions[0] := 'Button-1';
 CustomButtonCaptions[1] := 'Button-2';
 CustomButtonCaptions[2] := 'Button-3';
 CustomButtonCaptions[3] := 'Button-4';
 CustomButtonCaptions[4] := 'Button-5';

  case MessageDlg('MSG',TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation,mbYesAllNoAllCancel,0,TMsgDlgBtn.mbClose,CustomButtonCaptions) of
      0:
      begin

      end;
  end;
end;
```

// Or

```
MessageDlg('MSG',TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation,mbYesAllNoAllCancel,0,TMsgDlgBtn.mbClose, ['Button-1','Button-2','Button-3','Button-4','Button-5']);
```

[image]

Comment: Since the parameter is an open array parameter, you don't even need to declare a dynamic array variable.

Comment: `MessageDlg('Where do you want to go today?', TMsgDlgType.mtCustom, mbOKCancel, 0, TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK, ['Redmond', 'New York'])`.

Comment: unexpected things from delphi :D , let me add this code to the example

Comment: There's very much no need for `VarArrayOf` here. If you absolutely must create a dynamic array, you should do it like this: `TArray<string>.Create('Redmond', 'New York')`.

Comment: I hadn't realised that you have to change the Message Type, my bad  Thank you @Andreas Rejbrand

Comment: From now on I will use the @Andreas Rejbrand's fluent task dialog interface.  Thank you for pointing me at that.